# PowerShell to read bunch of log file to add computers to a group in Active Directory and export a CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

On a Windows Server, a task is launched every day to correct permissions on DNS on specific records and log them to a CSV file (Date,ComputerName).

This script is running since a year, and there is a lot of log files now...

I need to be able to:

1. Read all the log files
2. Add each computer to an AD group
3. Count how many times a computer is logged from the beginning
4. Export this to another csv file
5. Export a kind of abstract
6. Launch this script at the end of the original script

I can't modify the original script which is launched every day at 7AM each 10 minutes for 12 hours. For the moment, I have to work with the log files (.CSV) which are in the same directory

The script Append content to a CSV file like this:

```
$tagfile=get-date -format "ddMMyyyy"
$logfile="C:\Logs\Taches Planifiées\Correctif permissions enregistrements DNS\CorrectionsDNS_$tagfile.csv"
#some code
"$timestamp,$pcname"|Add-content -Path $logfile
```

Each CSV file is like this:

```
20-06-2019-08:00:03,PO038281
20-06-2019-08:10:03,PO042080
20-06-2019-08:20:05,PC040752
20-06-2019-08:20:05,PO041927
20-06-2019-08:20:05,PO047187
20-06-2019-08:30:05,PO046931
...
```

I wrote a script which loops on each CSV file to

```
$Global:path = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$objLogs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where{$_.Name -like "CorrectionsDNS_*.csv"})){
    ForEach($line in Get-Content $file){
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Date" -value $line.SubString(0,10)
        $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hour" -value ($line.Split("-")[3]).Split(",")[0]
        $obj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Computer" -value ($line.Split("-")[3]).Split(",")[1]
        $objLogs += $obj
    }   
}
$csv = $path + "\" + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd.HH") + "h" + (Get-Date).ToString("mm") + ".LogsDNS.csv"
$objLogs | Export-CSV -Path $csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
if ((Get-ADGroup -Identity "ErreurDNS") -eq $false){
    New-ADGroup -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -Name "ErreurDNS" -Path: "OU=Ordinateurs,OU=Hotel du Departement,DC=cg53,DC=fr" -SamAccountName:"ErreurDNS"
}
ForEach ($member in ($objLogs.Computer | Group).Name){
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ErreurDNS" -Members (Get-ADComputer $member) -ErrorAction Ignore
}
```

It seems that goals 1,2 and 4 are OK.

Here is the .CSV file:

```
"Date";"Hour";"Computer"
"01-01-2019";"07:30:11";"PO042117"
"01-02-2019";"08:10:03";"PO042150"
"01-02-2019";"08:20:07";"PO042070"
"01-02-2019";"08:30:03";"PO041284"
...
```

But can you help me for the goals 3,5 and 6 if possible?

I've already tried this to group result by computers:

```
$objLogs.Computer | Group | Select Name,Count
```

But it is unreadable. Some computers count several amount of records but there aren't here anymore (replacement) or they haven't got the problem anymore since few weeks (reinstall, replacement)...

How can I write an abstract where I can easily see the computers where DNS records have been corrected and when without importing my CSV to Excel sheet each time?

LastWeek.csv

```
"";"Hour";"Computer"
"01-01-2019";"07:30:11";"PO042117"
"01-02-2019";"08:10:03";"PO042150"
"01-02-2019";"08:20:07";"PO042070"
"01-02-2019";"08:30:03";"PO041284"
...
```

LastMonth.csv, LastYear.csv ...

Comment: How could `I can't modify the original script` and point 6 match? BTW I would `Import-Csv` the log (supplying headers if necessary) and cast/convert the datetime stamp to [datetime] type and **NOT** split them into two fields. Also adding with `+=` is very inefficient as it rebuilds the array each time.

Comment: @LotPings The original script is actually used in production. But i can effectively work on a copy but it will correct the DNS entries just for test and i don't want to do that on production. So, i'm trying to work on another script wich i will simple call on a try/catch a the end ... And thanks for your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment,

- convert to a [datetime]
- Group-Object by Computer
- evaluate first,last encounter of the computer in the logs
- output stats ( or save as another csv file with `Export-Csv`)

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\20\SO_56684868.ps1
$Global:path = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

$objLogs = ForEach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $path\CorrectionsDNS_*.csv)){
    Import-Csv $file -Header DateTime,Computer | ForEach-Object{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.DateTime,"dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss",[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
            Computer = $_.Computer
        }
    }
}

$stats = $objLogs | Group-Object Computer | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Computer = $_.Name
        Count    = $_.Count
        FirstEnc = ($_.Group.DateTime|Sort-Object)[0]
        LastEnc  = ($_.Group.DateTime|Sort-Object -Descending)[0]
    }
}
$stats
```

Sample output based on some additions to above data. (datetime format as per my locale settings)

```
> . Q:\Test\2019\06\20\SO_56684868.ps1

Computer Count FirstEnc            LastEnc
-------- ----- --------            -------
PO038281     2 2019-05-20 08:00:03 2019-06-20 08:00:03
PO042080     2 2019-04-20 08:10:03 2019-06-20 08:10:03
PC040752     2 2019-03-20 08:20:05 2019-06-20 08:20:05
PO041927     2 2019-02-20 08:20:05 2019-06-20 08:20:05
PO047187     2 2019-01-20 08:20:05 2019-06-20 08:20:05
PO046931     2 2019-01-10 08:30:05 2019-06-20 08:30:05
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works as expected and i can sort as i want ! In fact, i'm going to only add computers to the specified group in the first script and let me (or colleague) launch the .ps1 to export the csv and with a `$stats | Out-GridView` to show it directly.